# apt mirror not providing a specific package version

Tags: apt, apt-mirror

I have a private mirror setup mostly to keep older version of packages. Recently I faced and issue where a specific version of the package which I wanted to install are not available via apt even though it is present in my repo. For example:

```
[client-vm01]# apt-cache policy base-files
base-files:
  Installed: 12ubuntu4.4
  Candidate: 12ubuntu4.6
  Version table:
     12ubuntu4.6 500
        500 http://repo.private/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
 *** 12ubuntu4.4 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     12ubuntu4 500
        500 http://repo.private/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package base-files is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  motd-news-config

E: Version '12ubuntu4.5' for 'base-files' was not found
```

base-files-12ubuntu4.5 is present in the private repo and I'm able to download it via curl, but apt does not see this version.

```
[repo-server] # find . -name "base-files*"
./pool/main/b/base-files/base-files_12ubuntu4.6_amd64.deb
./pool/main/b/base-files/base-files_12ubuntu4.4_amd64.deb
./pool/main/b/base-files/base-files_12ubuntu4_amd64.deb
./pool/main/b/base-files/base-files_12ubuntu4.5_amd64.deb
```

Is this due to missing repo meta-data or something else ? How can I fix this ?